# how to solve the #text during data-binding in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following data-binding with knockout. The web service returning xml so i did the mapping from xml to json as follow:

```
var jsonResponse = xmlToJson(msg);
ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonResponse.Category.SubCategories.SubCategory[0], {}, viewModel.dataRow);
```

When i debug in the chrome browser i can display the name property as follow:

```
jsonResponse.Category.SubCategories.SubCategory[0].Name['#text']: "Basket"
```

However during the data-binding in markup, I am having an error.

i tried both:

```
<li data-bind="text: Name()"></li> and <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
```

Console log ERROR:

```
Message: Name is not defined
```

Anyone knows how to solve the #text during data-binding in knockout ?

**EDIT:**

@Robert - you almost shed the light i modified the code as follow, **it has no console log err but it does not display anything, any ideas?**

js:

```
var jsonResponse = xmlToJson(msg);
viewModel.dataRow = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonResponse.Category.SubCategories.SubCategory[0]);
```

markup (now it has context):

```
<div data-bind="with: dataRow">
  <ul>
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update the HTML with the parent element(s) where the foreach (I'm assuming) data-bind expression is.  We need it for the context

Comment: knockout has a feature to allow you to look at the binding context for any element.  Select the LI element in the dev tools.  Chrome assigns the current element to a special value in the console "$0".  Execute the following ( without quotes ):  "ko.dataFor($0)"  This will show you the current object (should be the value of dataRow).  ko.contextFor($0) might also be helpful

Comment: You'll probably find that "Name" is an object itself.  Try using "text: Name['#text']" or something similar

Comment: Another trick is to use <span data-bind="JSON.stringify($data)"></span>

Comment: Correction--- Another trick is to use <span data-bind="text: JSON.stringify($data)"></span>

Comment: is there anyway to direct binding knockout with xml btw? it screws the  object structure while converting xml to json

Comment: No, xml is not a native structure in JS.  You need to convert it to a javascript object... There are a couple of libraries you could use... we use x2js -> https://code.google.com/p/x2js/